# Is it possible to access a C variable from a linker script

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, linker, linker-scripts

Let's say for example I need to get the size of the process loaded into memory then I define this in my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

ssize_t prog_sz;
int main()
{
     printf("%x\n", prog_sz);
}
```

then I have a linker script accessing it with a line like this `proc_sz = .`

NOTE: all linker scripts I test with my programs always produce errors which is why I specified only a line from the script. For example something as simple as this without that line I first talked about:

```
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
}
```

produces annoying errors like these:

```
/usr/bin/ld: a.out: error: PHDR segment not covered by LOAD segment
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): in function `__libc_csu_init':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
/usr/bin/ld: a.out: hidden symbol `__init_array_end' isn't defined
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

even an example from the ld info documentation produces that annoying error. Maybe you can help me solve that issue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two separate issues.

The first issue involves the symbol/variable `prog_sz`.  The approach that you have shown will just cause the linker to try and create another symbol named `prog_sz`, which would not likely accomplish the goal.

Without further detail on exactly what is being done, I will present three objectives and their solution:

1. Set the variable `prog_sz` to contain the address of a symbol defined in the linker file.

Define the symbol in your command file with a different name, such as `prog_sz__`.  You can then add  directly above the declaration of `prog_sz` in your code the line:

`extern char prog_sz;`

The type `char` does not really matter here.  This statement is just necessary to tell the compiler that the symbol will be defined somewhere else.  After this, you can assign the address of the symbol to `prog_sz` by modifying your definition to:

`size_t prog_sz = (size_t)(&prog_sz__);`

Using `&` tells the program to store the address associated with symbol `prog_sz__` in variable `prog_sz`.  This will assign the symbol defined in your linker script to your variable `prog_sz`.

2. Position the variable at a fixed location using the linker script there is a way to do this.

Assuming that you are using the GNU toolchain, when you are building use the GCC option `-fdata-sections`.  This will place each variable into its own data section.  Be aware that your `.bss` and `.data` sections will be replaced with a section for each variable prefixed `.data` or `.bss` and you may need to use a wildcard `*` to capture the `.bss` and `.data` sections.

You can then add a section just below the location in the linker file where `.` is set to the desired address.

For example:

```
SECTION
{
...

    . = where_i_want_prog_sz;
    prog_sz_section :
    {
        * (.bss.prog_sz)
    }
...
}
```

Note that this will store `prog_sz` at a specific location, but will not set `prog_sz` to the value of the location.

3. Treat a linker symbol defined in the command file as a `size_t` variable.

Define the variable using the `extern` keyword: `extern size_t prog_sz;`

This tells the compiler that the symbol is defined elsewhere but will be of type size_t.  Keep in mind, if this is what is being done, then you will need to be sure that the memory location is not being used for anything else, otherwise prog_sz may overlap other data in the system.

Regarding the second issue, which is the list of linker error messages, I believe that you may not have the linker configured correctly.  Symbols `__init_array_end` and `__init_array_start` are related to initializing the C programming environment.  I would suggest reviewing the linker settings and documentation to make sure that the program is properly configured.  If you are using the GNU toolchain, you can find documentation here:

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.37/

Comment: Thank you this, though the question was about creating a variable in C and accessing it in the linker script your answer shows that it can't be done because the linker would just create another symbol. Even though this question was asked in regards to my os I guess I should solve the issues. Can you point me to any resource explaining how to configure the settings properly.

Comment: Regarding linker documentation, if you are using GNU tools, I would take a look here: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.37/ld.pdf.

Comment: I added some further detail regarding options for variable `prog_sz`.  Hopefully one of these will cover what you are looking for.